# What are functions in decltype not called?

Tags: c++

I was messing around with templates and I found that functions that are called in a decltype statement are not executed, provided is an example:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
auto Call(Func func, Args&&... args) -> decltype(func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
  return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void main()
{
  std::cout << Call([](int x, int y){ std::cout << x << y << std::endl; return true; }, 1, 2) << std::endl;
  std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Why is this? I'm not trying to make it be called in the statement, I am simply curious as to why this is so.

Comment: Because that's the way `decltype`  (like `sizeof`) is specified.    If given an expression, it evaluates the type that would result if the expression was evaluated.   It does not evaluate the expression.

Comment: If the expression inside `decltype` in your example were evaluated, when and how often would that evaluation happen?